# A closed form of $\frac{1}{2k+1}+\frac{2k}{(2k+1)(2k-1)}+\ldots+\frac{2k(2k-2)\cdots 4}{(2k+1)(2k-1)\cdots 3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, factorial

Is there a closed form representation of the following sum?

$$\frac{1}{2k+1}+\frac{2k}{(2k+1)(2k-1)}+\frac{2k(2k-2)}{(2k+1)(2k-1)(2k-3)}+\cdots+\frac{2k(2k-2)\cdots 6\cdot 4}{(2k+1)!!}.$$

Here $k$ is a positive integer and $!!$ is the double factorial.

Comment: Where is the identity?

Comment: Why have you stopped at $k=3$, and the factor of $\frac{1}{2k+1}$ is easy to remove.

Comment: @FormulaWriter sorry there is no identity. Typo fixed. Thanks

Comment: @Peter Foreman Yes. That is what I meant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let this sum be $S_k$; then $S_1=1/3$ and $(2k+1)S_k=1+2kS_{k-1}$ for $k>1$. The closed form is $$S_k=1-\frac{(2k)!!}{(2k+1)!!}$$ because it satisfies the same recurrence and initial condition (therefore it holds by induction on $k$).

Simply put, if you stop the summation at $\frac{2k(2k-2)\cdots 2}{(2k+1)(2k-1)\cdots 1}$ instead, the sum becomes equal to $1$.

Comment: Thank you. I have no experience dealing with sums like this, so I don't have a clue for it.